# Incremental Decision Tree C++ Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, classification

Do anyone know any incremental implementation of decision tree classifier. Such that it could generate optimal decision tree classifier when you add new instance to training set with low computation and as quick as possible according existing decision tree classifier?

In other words I have an optimal decision tree classifier of set **A**, which named **T_1**, now I want to add instance **X** to set **A** and find optimal decision tree classifier tree **T_2** by taking advantage of **T_1** and **X** for set **{A,X}**.

adding instances will occurs several times. So it will valuable for me to find incremental method instead of building the tree every time.

Actually I am suspicious whether such implementation exists or not. It is appreciated if anybody could help me. I prefer code in c++ if there is any.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_decision_tree) article links to two codes.  [ITI](http://www-lrn.cs.umass.edu/iti/index.html) is not open source, but the source is avalable, [VMFL](http://www.cs.washington.edu/dm/vfml/) is open source and in C (mostly)

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/greenfish77/gaenari
c++ head-only incremental decision tree open-source.

it learns a tree from weak-instances, and merge it to model.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31245728)